# ThoughtCrime sslstrip installation tar

Tags: software-installation

```
matt@matt-macbook:$ sudo tar zxvf sslstrip-0.9.tar.gz
tar (child): sslstrip-0.9.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I install this software?

Comment: in which folder `sslstrip-0.9.tar.gz` was located?

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused mainly because of you forget to add  the full pathname of that file you are trying to extract.

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/where/tar.gz/file/is/located
sudo tar -zxvf sslstrip-0.9.tar.gz
```

This will extract the tar.gz file to the same directory where tar.gz file is located.

OR

```
sudo tar -xzvf /full/path/to/sslstrip-0.9.tar.gz
```

This will extract `tar.gz` file to the `/home/$USER` directory.

[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)